# Elasticsearch: adding document with completion suggester, maximum value of the weight

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch I can index documents with support for completion suggester by using something like:

```
PUT music/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "suggest": [
    {
      "input": "Nevermind",
      "weight": 10
    }
  ]
}
```

The `weight` parameter affects the score when suggest query is issued.
The documentation stats that `weight` should be a positive integer but it does not talk about any maximum value, what is the maximum value I can use for the weight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to find out by putting a very high value to make it error out, but [according to the code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/253c53d4ec6dcd76cbc82d94deef16e958d00303/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/mapper/CompletionFieldMapper.java#L433-L435), the valid interval for weights are the range of positive integers, so `[0..2147483647]`